# New rails project server exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

Ruby version: `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]`

Rails version: `4.2.3`

Mac OSX: `10.10.4`

When I create a new rails project: `rails new proj --database=postgres`

(I still have the same issue without the database flag)

Then run the server:
`rails server`

The server starts, but when I visit '/' I get 1 of 2 different errors:

`undefined method 'default_timezone=' for #<Class:0x007f970ce355d0>`

`Database URL cannot be empty`

All my config files have not been touched in anyway. Setting host, username, password, url, etc in database.yml has had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try adding these lines in the `application.rb`: `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`.

Comment: I added the lines, No change. What are you thinking the problem might be?

Comment: I had this problem once, then I completely uninstalled Ruby, Rails, Rbenv and Database server (MySQL). Then I installed the latest versions of all of them. And after that I created a fresh new application `rails new myapp` and everything was solved.

Comment: @AbraarAriqueDiganto LOL ... did you also buy a new server?